# Sound output issues Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

I'm having a sound output issue with Ubuntu 20.04 when I connect remotely to laptop using Anydesk on the latest versions on both the laptop and my Android phone.It works fine on other Debian based distros but not Ubuntu.I am not using Wayland either.
HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15m-ds0xxx